# How to reduce Java List object size based on bytes

Tags: java, list, sizeof

I have a Java list of long strings, and I'm using `net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf` to attempt to find the size and reduce this list 1 by 1 until the total List object size is <= 50000 bytes.  My code below has horrible performance.

```
    import net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf;

    List<String> mySuperLongStrings;   // this list contains thousands of long strings

    Long size = SizeOf.deepSizeOf(mySuperLongStrings); 

    while (size > Long.valueOf(50000)) {
        if (!mySuperLongStrings.isEmpty()) {
            mySuperLongStrings.remove(0);
            size = SizeOf.deepSizeOf(mySuperLongStrings);
        } 
    }
```

Any recommendations on how this could be done ?

Comment: What does "horrible" mean?

Comment: Have you tried just subtracting the size of the item you removed rather than getting the size of the List for every loop iteration?

Comment: `ArrayList` will suck at `remove(0)`; it will take linear time.  Try removing from the end of the list rather than the beginning.

Comment: Is it also possible to remove from the tail of the list, or is it intended to always remove the first item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Size.deepSizeOf(list)` has to iterate the entire list every time, your algorithm has a quadratic runtime complexity. You can easily change it to linear, if you just sum up the sizes of the strings within your list individually, stopping as soon as it exceeds the limit of 50000 bytes:

```
public static <T> List<T> sizedSubList(List<T> list, long maxSize) {
    long totalSize = 0;
    int i = list.size() - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        totalSize += SizeOf.deepSizeOf(list.get(i));
        if (totalSize > maxSize) break;
        i--;
    }

    return list.subList(i + 1, list.size());
}
```

(The result might be slightly larger than `maxSize`, as this algorithm doesn't take the size of the list object itself - including the internal storage array - into account).

Usage:

```
List<String> smallList = sizedSubList(largeList, 50000);
```

*Note that the sub-list returned by this method is just a view of the original list, so subsequent modifications of the original list will be reflected by the sub-list and vice versa.*

Comment: Nice, that might work.  I'll have to test. Is there a way to modify the passed in list  instead of returning a list ?  (i.e. a void method)

Comment: Sure: `list.subList(0, i + 1).clear()` removes the first (i+1) elements from list

Comment: hum, that would be  `list.subList(0, i - 1).clear()`     no ?

Comment: No. end index is exclusive. As i+1 is the first index of the items to retain, it is exactly what we want.

Comment: Sorry but no.  Consider this example :  2 objects in the list.   On the first iteration (`i = 1` since `list.size() = 2`), if the `totalSize > maxSize`, then that is doing `list.subList(0, 2).clear()` which removes the 2 objects.

Comment: Well, sorry, that is correct but in my case no.  I want to keep at least one. So yes, you are correct !  thanks alot isnot2bad !

Comment: Hehe. Of course, you should rethink this algorithm and adopt it to your special needs: Take the first n items vs. the last n; include or exclude the item that makes your list grow beyond max size; return a sublist vs. a new list vs. modify the original list; and so on. My code should just be a starting point.